# Two labels in the same matrix node

Tags: tikz-matrix

I'd like to label two objects (two characters) in the same matrix node, in such a way to draw an arrow from the node above to each of the objects in the lower node. More precisely, I would like to draw one arrow from `|(C3)| C\textsubscript{3}` to `|(c3)| \textipa{n}`, and one from `|(C3)| C\textsubscript{3}` to `|(c3)| \textcolor{Gray}{\textipa{g}}`.
Here you have the code. Can you help me out?

```
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.75em, column sep={2em,between origins}, row 3/.style={font=\scshape}] 
{ 
|(C1)| C\textsubscript{1}   & |(V1)| \textcolor{Gray}{V\textsubscript{1}}   & |(C2)| C\textsubscript{2} & |(V2)| V\textsubscript{2} & |(C3)| C\textsubscript{3} & |(V3)| V\textsubscript{3}     \\
|(c1)| \textipa{t}          &                           & |(c2)| \textcolor{Gray}{\textipa{j}}      & |(v2)| \textipa{E}        & |(c3)| \textipa{n} \textcolor{Gray}{\textipa{g}}      &                                               \\
}; 
 
\draw [<->] (C1) to (c1); 
\draw [->][color=Gray] (C2) to (c2); 
\draw [<->] (V2) to (v2);
\draw [<->] (C3) to (c3);

\draw [<->] (c2) to (c1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Where is defined `\textipa`?. Please always provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which we can copy and compile in our computers. Also a sketch, what you like to have is welcome!

Comment: Well, due to your temporary reputation, you can't upvote answers (to do this, you need at least 16 credits), but you can accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer), which you estimate that solve your problem on the best way.

Comment: Any news?  Already a month ago you receive two answers which solve your problem. It would be nice, that you accept one of the, (which solve your problem on the best way) by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer. By this you will close this thread as solved and award one of contributors.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for your comment. I didn't know I had to follow the procedure you explained. I thought it was enough answering and thanking the ones who reacted. I hope now it's better

Comment: Dear  Edoardo Cavirani, this is policy of site. Thank you for your response. Noe you earn two points of reputation :-). Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that are you after something like this:

[image]

Image is drawn by use of the `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={inner sep=1pt}},
                   column sep=tiny, 
                   arrows=<->, >={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
                  ]
C_1  \ar[d] &|[text=Gray]| V_1  
                & C_2 \ar[d]  
                    & V_2 \ar[d,->] 
                            & C_3 \ar[d,start anchor=250, end anchor={[xshift=-1ex]north}]
                                  \ar[d,gray,
                                        start anchor=290, end anchor={[xshift=+1ex]north}]
                                &  V_3    \\
t \ar[rr]   &   &|[text=Gray]| j     
                    & E     & {n}\; \textcolor{Gray}{g}    
                                &  
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution keeping the `matrix of nodes`.
You can use anchor based on the angle around the node (for instance `\draw [<->] (C3.250) to (c3.120);`), or use predefined anchors as in `\draw [<->] (C3.south) to ($(c3.north)!.5!(c3.north east)$);`. Of course you can change the values I set up!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \matrix [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.75em, column sep={2em,between origins}, row 3/.style={font=\scshape}] 
    { 
        |(C1)| C\textsubscript{1}   & |(V1)| \textcolor{gray}{V\textsubscript{1}}   & |(C2)| C\textsubscript{2} & |(V2)| V\textsubscript{2} & |(C3)| C\textsubscript{3} & |(V3)| V\textsubscript{3}     \\
        |(c1)| \textipa{t}          &                           & |(c2)| \textcolor{gray}{\textipa{j}}      & |(v2)| \textipa{E}        & |(c3)| \textipa{n} \textcolor{gray}{\textipa{g}}      &                                               \\
    }; 
    
    \draw [<->] (C1) to (c1); 
    \draw [->, color=gray] (C2) to (c2); 
    \draw [<->] (V2) to (v2);
    \draw [<->] (C3.250) to (c3.120);
    \draw [<->, gray] (C3.south) to ($(c3.north)!.5!(c3.north east)$);
    
    \draw [<->] (c2) to (c1);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks nice like this